# Unable to store special characters in github secrets

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

I am trying to store my password as GitHub secret. However, I am getting **401 unauthorized** error. It appears to me that the GitHub secrets doesn't work if the value contains a special character.
The value that I am trying to store has '$' in it? How could I possibly store the value `Ri$hab` in Github secrets in order to make it work ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use escape character before the special character like: Ri\$hab

[image]

Comment: How would you store a `{` character? `\\` doesn't seem to work for that

Comment: We are using single quotes: `'Ri$hab'` - maybe that helps with `{`

Answer (score 0):

I tried on a project of mine, and I don't have this problem, the secret is created sucessfully...

A 401 Error could mean you don't have the rights on this repository.

Also, there are rules on the name of your secret

> Secret names cannot include any spaces or start with the GITHUB_ prefix.

[image]

Comment: The secrets will be cretaed successfully but it doesn't work. It is unable to store the characters after $

Comment: Then your problem is about using a Github Secret, no storing it, right ? Why do you say "it doesn't work" ? Please add details to your question

Comment: @RishabPrasad have you find any solution for this?